# Flow Radio Buttons labels are not aligned with the actual values

Tags: lwc

I have a Screen flow that is used in an LWC component in a community page

The screen flow has some radio button fields.

The language used is right to left.

The problem is that the labels are not aligned to the right as the values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMry2.jpg)

I tried other SLDS with no luck

slds-form-element__label and slds-form-element__legend

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [ask] and then [edit] your question and post the code so that people may be able to help you fix it - because, essentially, you are saying that your code does not give you your desired result and you need help fixing it and people can't help you fix the code if they can't see the code.

Comment: It's just a screen flow that is displayed on the community page via an LWC. I will add the code and see if it helps to get better responses.